# how to access the $query variable inside taxonomy-xxx.php template file?

Tags: custom-taxonomy, templates, query, template-hierarchy, tax-query

In my custom template files, I create query in the following way:

```
<?php $query = new WP_Query(array('post_type' => 'aya-bi-aya','author' => $current_user->ID,'paged' => $paged, 'post_status' => array('publish') ) ); ?>
```

And to perform pagination, I call pagination function after loop like:

```
<?php my_pagination($query->max_num_pages);?>
```

But in my `taxonomy-xxx.php`, when I call pagination the same way, I get the warning:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: query in C:\xampp\htdocs\balagha-to-alquran\production\wp-content\themes\twentyten\taxonomy-dawahir-balaghia.php on line 186

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\balagha-to-alquran\production\wp-content\themes\twentyten\taxonomy-dawahir-balaghia.php on line 186
```

Can you please help me resolve this issue? your help is appreciated.

**Edit and solution:**

My pagination function:

```
function my_pagination($pages = '', $range = 2)
{  
     $showitems = ($range * 2)+1;  

     global $paged;
     if(empty($paged)) $paged = 1;

     if($pages == '')
     {
         global $wp_query;
         $pages = $wp_query->max_num_pages;
         if(!$pages)
         {
             $pages = 1;
         }
     }   

     if(1 != $pages)
     {
         echo "<div class='pagination'>";

         if($paged > 2 && $paged > $range+1 && $showitems < $pages) echo "<a href='".get_pagenum_link(1)."'>&laquo;</a>";
         if($paged > 1 && $showitems < $pages) echo "<a href='".get_pagenum_link($paged - 1)."'>&lsaquo;</a>";

         for ($i=1; $i <= $pages; $i++)
         {
             if (1 != $pages &&( !($i >= $paged+$range+1 || $i <= $paged-$range-1) || $pages <= $showitems ))
             {
                 echo ($paged == $i)? "<span class='current'>".$i."</span>":"<a href='".get_pagenum_link($i)."' class='inactive' >".$i."</a>";
             }
         }

         if ($paged < $pages && $showitems < $pages) echo "<a href='".get_pagenum_link($paged + 1)."'>&rsaquo;</a>";  
         if ($paged < $pages-1 &&  $paged+$range-1 < $pages && $showitems < $pages) echo "<a href='".get_pagenum_link($pages)."'>&raquo;</a>";
         echo "</div>\n";
     }
}
```

I resolved the issue by removing the argument from the function call(`$query->max-num-pages`) in my `taxonomy-xx.php` since the argument is not mandatory. As you can see, there is an if statement inside the function that deals with the absence of argument by calling the global `$wp_query`. 
Thank you.

Comment: Please **edit your question** to include the full (relevant) code of your `taxonomy-xx.php` taxonomy template file, as well as the declaration for `function my_pagination()`.

Comment: but don't you want the `max_num_pages` from your `$query`, and not `$wp_query`?

Comment: I'm wondering why, if the `taxonomy-xx.php` template file is being used correctly, pagination isn't working *out of the box*. I suspect a (n unnecessary) custom query.

Comment: I really don't fully understand you Milo and Chip Bennett, I am a beginner that still should learn in the Wordpress realm.

Answer (score 1):

Is the `my_pagination()` call within the same file as your `$query` declaration?

If not, you need to put `global $query;` at the top of your template file where `my_pagination()` is being called.

If this doesn't solve it, please give some more information/code examples.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. The second solution unfortunately doesnt work. I will try to call `global $query` inside of my pagination function and give a feedback here plus some more information

Comment: Well. Since I didn't create the pagination function myself, I didn't notice that inside, there is possibility to do not give first parameter. In this case, the function automatically uses global wp_query to calculate the max_num_pages. Thank you anyway for your help.

Comment: Glad I could be of assistance. It's always recommended to alter `$wp_query` directly through the `pre_get_posts` action, if you're interested in best practices.

Comment: Thank you very much Sir, your advise is invaluable. Good luck